# need recursive query and stored procedure in teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, while-loop, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have the below excel stored in a table,where I need to search some pattern using tera data stored procedure and recursive function in tera data. I have written a query but its going in an endless loop. Please help me with this

```
Fruit_name      Type              Schedule

Orange          Equal to           Banana
pineapple       Equal to         Straberry
Banana          Equal to           Lichi
Lichi           direct          pineapple
```

So basically the script that I will write will start from fruitname=Orange it check if the column type has a value direct or not if not the the third column i.e schedule whatever the value in that will be checked again in fruit name i.e banana will b check in fruit_name column again for the second time and the loop goes until the column 2 has a value "direct". so in above example the loop will run 3 times and when the fruit is lichi the loop stops. as the type for lichi is direct and the loop ends

Below is the procedure i wrote

Please help me with this.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE fruit_name(OUT VAR5 Varchar(20)) 
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE VAR_TYPE VARCHAR (20);
    DECLARE VAR_TYPE1 VARCHAR (20);
    DECLARE VAR_SCHEDULE VARCHAR (20);

   select type  into VAR_TYPE from test_table where fruit_name='Orange';
   select SCHEDULE  into VAR_SCHEDULE from test_table where fruit_name='Orange';
   while(Type<>'Direct') do
   BEGIN


    select  type  into VAR_TYPE from test_table where fruie_name=VAR_SCHEDULE;
    select  schedule  into VAR_TYPE1 from TSSC10W.test_table where 
    fruit_name=VAR_SCHEDULE;
    set VAR_SCHEDULE=VAR_TYPE1;


    END;

    END while; 


    set VAR5=VAR_SCHEDULE;


END;
```

Same loop i need to write using recursive function as well.

Help Appreciated

Comment: Your current logic is correct, there's probably some bad data...

Comment: the logic that i wrote is goin in the endless loop thats the reason I m nt getting any O/P

Comment: Again, your logic is correctly traversing the data, but there must be some bad data, either there's no final `'Direct'`  or there's a back-reference like `orange -> banana -> lichi -> orange`

Comment: Hi Can you please  help me changing this in recursive function?

Comment: For recursion you need to know where to start, i.e. you need a seed query returning the first level, `orange`.